# Flutter app MultiProvider with StreamProviders that depends on eachother

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, provider

In my application I use a StreamProvider on the whole app (on the whole MaterialApp) that provides the state of the user (whether he is logged in or not, and he's uid if he's logged in). I want provide the whole MaterialApp with the live UserData from Firebase, so I need to use a StreamProvider in a MultiProvider that wraps the whole MaterialApp. But the problem is that to get the UserData from Firebase, I need to get the uid of the user, so I can't use the StreamProviders of the user state and uid and the one that provides UserData.
My code looks like this:

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    StreamProvider.value(
      value: AuthService().getUser(),
    ),
    StreamProvider<UserData>.value(
      value: DatabaseRepository(uid: HERE I NEED THE UID FROM THE PREVIOUS PROVIDER).getUserDataStream(),
      child: Tabs(),
      catchError: (ctx, e) {
        print('error: $e');

        return UserData(
          uid: null,
          username: null,
          email: null,
        );
      },
    ),
  ],
```

What should I do to get the uid from the first StreamProvider and use it in the second one to get the user data?

Comment: Use ProxyProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried two logics. In case of 1st pattern, unfortunately I could get "UserData" in the Tabs class. But 2nd pattern, it worked well.

```
/// 1st Pattern
MultiProvider(
    providers: [
        StreamProvider<User>.value(value: AuthService().getUser(),),
        ProxyProvider<User, StreamProvider<UserData>>(
            update: (context, value, previous) {
                return StreamProvider<UserData>.value(value: 
                    DatabaseRepository(uid:User.uid).getUserDataStream(),);
            }
        )
    ],
    child: Tabs(),
);

/// 2nd Pattern
MultiProvider(
    providers: [
        StreamProvider<User>.value(value: AuthService().getUser(),),
    ],
    child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
            final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
            return MultiProvider(
                providers: [
                    StreamProvider<UserData>.value(value: 
                        DatabaseRepository(uid:user.uid).getUserDataStream(),)
                ],
                child: Tabs()
            ); 
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: Sorry for my rough type. I corrected my code.